# Stnadard deviation of values containing different ranges

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, normalization, numpy

Taking the $\sigma$ of these values :

```
np.std([55,50,40,45])
```

returns:

```
 5.59
```

If I take the $\sigma$ of these values:

```
np.std([1,15,14,13])
```

returns a similar value:

```
5.67
```

Is there a statistic which informs how significant the $\sigma$ is for a given set of numbers without being aware of the values magnitude ?

In this example I conclude the  $\sigma$ of `[1,15,14,13]` is more pertinent than $\sigma$ of `[55,50,40,45]` as `[1,15,14,13]` contains the value `1` which an outlier in `[1,15,14,13]`. The values `[55,50,40,45]` have a similar $\sigma$ but while each value is close to it's $\mu$ its not as pertinent.

Is there a measure for this pertinence ?

Perhaps the solution is to normalize values both sets: `[1,15,14,13]` & `[55,50,40,45]` and then recalculate the $\sigma$ for each ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard deviation of a sampling of an underlying population has some error on itself, you can also find a confidence interval ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Confidence_interval_of_a_sampled_standard_deviation)). As the question already mentions, it can be that you can have the case where while drawing the first four samples there is one sample which is an outlier. However also this outlier is part of the underlying population.
To get a value for the uncertainty on the standard deviation, one can make a least square fit of the data to a normal distribution, which gives you as result bounds next to the best fit value. For details on least square fit see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).